# <img>: force display of alt text on 404

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-404

Consider a trivial HTML file:

```
<html lang="en"><body>
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/qqqqq.jpg" alt="ERROR"><br>
<img src="https://iili.io/qqqqq.jpg" alt="ERROR"><br>
</body></html>
```

Both images do not exist.

For the first image, the server returns a 404 with no content, and the browser displays the "ERROR" alt text as intended.

However, for the second image, the server returns a 404 status

[image]

but *also* sends content

[image: 404]

and the image in the content is shown rather than the alt text.

Is there a way to force the alt text to be shown if the status indicates an error even if an image was sent in the content?

(I also tried using `onerror` but it isn't triggered in such cases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server returns a 404 status code and sends an image as the response content, the `onload` event will still be triggered for the `<img>` element. The `onerror` event will not be triggered in this case because the browser successfully loaded an image resource, even though it may not be the expected image.

I can think of two possible solutions for this situation:

- Server-side solution: Instead of directly requesting the images from `"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/qqqqq.jpg" or "https://iili.io/qqqqq.jpg"`, you can set up your own server. Modify the image response content on the server-side before sending it to the client. This way, you can control the behavior of the image and handle the error condition appropriately.
- Client-side solution: In the `onload` event handler, you can check the loaded image and compare it with the error image. For example:

  ```
  <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/qqqqq.jpg" alt="ERROR" onload="handleLoad(this)" id="img1"><br>
  <img src="https://iili.io/qqqqq.jpg" alt="ERROR" onload="handleLoad(this)" id="img2"><br>

  function handleLoad(ele) {
    //simple comparison or use 3rd library for deep comparisons
    if (ele.width == 160 && ele.height == 160) {
      ele.src = "error";
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks you very much, client-side worked for me using `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties.  Can you tell me how to shift the alt text up x pixels?

Comment: You can style alt text like `img {font-size: 40px}`